# Cygwin, how to run "make" for all makefiles found in the root directory and any subdirectories?

Tags: windows, makefile, cygwin

I have a directory composed of various subdirectories.  In each of these subdirectories is a makefile. In the root directory, there is also a make file.  I need to perform a make instruction in cygwin that performs "make" on all makefiles in the main directory and any subdirectory.  Any ideas how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the common way I have seen it done. Inside of the "main" Makefile would be something similar to this code.

```
all:
    cd library  && $(MAKE) all && cd ..
    cd programs && $(MAKE) all && cd ..
    cd tests    && $(MAKE) all && cd ..
```

[**ref**](http://github.com/polarssl/polarssl/blob/master/Makefile)

Comment: make -C to avoid the &&s and explicit cds?